# Proper field type for numbers to ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, decimal-point

What's the proper field type for numbers in MySQL?

I have a field with numbers like 0.00, 4.12, 99.10, 130.99

So TINYINT or SMALLINT are not valid since they remove the decimal places to 0, 4, 131 etc.

When I cose VARCHAR I cannot properly ORDER BY because it sorts 99.10 after 130.99

Which type do I need? Highest number will not be larger than 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Column syntax:

```
`name` DECIMAL(<precision>,<scale>)
```

Note that `<precision>` is the *total* column length, so `DECIMAL(5,2)` is 3 digits before the decimal and 2 after.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose:

- Fixed-point: Decimal, numeric
- Floating-point: Float, double

You can find additional info on the corresponding [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: `numeric(6,2)` based on the sample data in the OP